# Single<String> at rxjava

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android

I want to get an output string from the server with the help of RXJava  and RetroFit Reader, but RXJava does not accept the string!

file api:

```
interface Api { 
    @POST("registerNumber.php")
    fun registerNumber(@Query("phoneNumber") number:String) : Single<String> }
```

error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Ccx.png)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use `SingleObserver<String>` instead of `SingleObserver<Single<String>>` as an argument for the `subscribe` method.